# Assigning address of structure to pointer of another structure

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I'm creating structures and pushing them to two vectors. While creating those structures i also sort them using lower_bound function. The first structure is sorted by name and the second structure is sorted by ID.

The function looks like :

```
bool AddAndSort ( name , ID )
{
  auto it = lower_bound ( arr_1 . begin (), arr_1  . end (), name, compare2 () );
  auto it1 = lower_bound( arr_2 . begin(), arr_2 .end(), ID , compare1 (  ) );

 struct1 tmp1( name ); // create temporary structures which i will push to the vector
 struct2 tmp( ID );

 arr_1 . insert ( it, tmp );
 arr_2 . insert ( it1, tmp1);

/*tmp . p = &tmp1;
  tmp1 . p = &tmp;*/

return true;

}
```

> Here is the question: How can i set pointers in those two structures
>   to point to each other?

I tried this :

```
tmp . p = &tmp1;
tmp1 . p = &tmp;
```

But this does not work.

Structures:

```
struct struct1
{
  struct1 ( string name ) : name ( name ) { }
  string name
  struct2 *p;
};

struct struct2
{
  struct2 ( int ID ) : ID ( ID ) { }
  int ID;
  struct1 *p;
}
```

vectors:

```
vector<struct1> arr_1
vector<struct2> arr_2
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get a compiler error? `index` doesn't exist in your structs, did you mean `p`?

Comment: sorry , i forgot to edit the name it should be p

Comment: Okay, you still need to post your compiler error. Also, `std::lower_bound` doesn't sort anything, and your function signature won't compiler.

Comment: I do not have any compiler error it just shows me some undefined characters and data when i print it.

Comment: `tmp` is not the same object, as the one that is inside the vector. When you insert a copy is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want:

```
auto inserted_it1 = arr_1.insert(it, tmp);
auto inserted_it2 = arr_2.insert(it1, tmp1);

inserted_it1->p = &*inserted_it2;
inserted_it2->p = &*inserted_it1;
```

but previous references are invalidated by `insert`.

Comment: What does first is supposed to mean?

Comment: @kvway: `first` was for insertion in `std::map`/`std::set`. Removed as `std::vector::insert` returns directly the iterator.

Comment: it works inside class method but when i declare another metod to print element from another struct im getting seg fault `for ( auto const & tmp : arr_2  ) cout << tmp . p -> name << endl;`  Don't you know why?

Comment: As I said, those references are very fragile as invalidated as soon as you call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

> The first structure is sorted by name and the second structure is sorted by ID

Check out [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html) - it can do exactly that (having multiple sorting indices) with just a single structure.

Because as pointed out, keeping pointers across structures can be error prone (the addresses change on insertion/deletion etc.). The `boost::multi_index` handles that automatically under the hood.